# How to use google calendar API for personnel project (Without verification)

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I'am using google calendar API on my personal project for creating events through python.But the problem is its asking to verify app by giving `privacy policy` details (Otherwise the token would expire after 7 days),which i think is overkill for a personnel project .Here iam using my own account and accessing my own data.So  is there any way that i can use google calendar API without verification,like for my own account.Or is it not possible to do so without verification.Or is there any other libraries to do the same thing,I just need to set events on my calendar Programmatically.Please help me!

Comment: personnel or personal?

Comment: its personal..!

Comment: btw...u got any solution?

Comment: you cannot avoid authorization, it is not only about your data, it is about unauth requests to google API

Comment: you can try [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) and refresh token when needed

Comment: As it has been said, you cannot completely avoid the authorization screen (you can read about how it all works [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)). Nevertheless, once you are "logged in" programmatically and have a token, there will be no need to sign in. You can achieve that by following any [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/quickstarts-overview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is create a "service account". Then you want create a new calendar for your (not the service account) calendar. Next, you share your new calendar with the service account by adding it under the "Share with specific people" section. Take note of the "Calendar ID" for this new calendar.

Now when you use the api you should add events from your service account to the new calendar by passing the calendar id as the calendarId.